# Proxy HTTP requests using subdomain

Tags: networking, proxy, https, dns, subdomain

I'm trying to get the following done:

1. A HTTP request comes into an address subdomain.domain.com to a public ip on a machine running a proxy (maybe apache? Anything better?)
2. Based on the subdomain, I'd like the request to be redirected to an internal machine on a private ip, and specific port. The response for that request will come from that internal machine.

What are my options? Any general guidelines out there for achieving this? Whats a good proxy implementation choice? Will also need to dynamically add subdomains over time, which redirect to specific internal ips/ports.

How do ssl certificates work in a setup with subdomains? Is a separate certificate required for every subdomain?

Comment: I think this question is more topical for serverfault.com. I've voted to migrate it there as well as answering it. If enough others agree it'll be moved for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup isn't too hard. You just make a virtual host for each subdomain and configure the vhosts as proxies. The approach is the same regardless of which proxy software you choose. I recommend you to use Nginx as an reverse proxy since the configuration is easier and the performance is much better than Apache. If you still want to use Apache, make sure you do not run PHP on the proxy machine and use mpm_worker instead of mpm_prefork.

You can make a script which adds new subdomains to the configuration file. It shouldn't be too hard since they will look almost the same, except for the path to the SSL certificate and the IP of the backbone server.

For SSL you can use a wildcard certificate which will cover the entire domain, including subdomains. This is not supported on all platforms, but the support have grown in the last years so it should be pretty safe.

Otherwise, without a wildcard certificate, you will need a certificate and a separate IP address per subdomain (since the SSL connection is set up before the domain name is known, you will need to differentiate different certificates by different IPs).

Answer (score 1):

Apache is perfectly reasonable for this problem. You can do virtual hosts which use [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xxx@yyy.com
    ServerName foo.yyy.com

    ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyErrorOverride On                       
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.1/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.1/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

If you were looking to host hundreds or thousands of sub-domains you could actually do this with [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) instead, with a trick involving local name lookups that allowed you to proxy `bar.yyy.com` to something like `local.bar.yyy.com`. Using mod_rewrite for mass virtual hosting is [mentioned in the apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html#simple.rewrite), using it to proxy instead of just rewrite is relatively straightforward. Doing it that way has the advantage that new sub domains can be added purely using DNS though.

In terms of SSL if you are just using `*.yyy.com` as the subdomains you can use a [wildcard certificate](https://serverfault.com/questions/193507/are-domain-com-wild-card-ssl-certificates-expected-to-or-required-to-only-be-us) (I neither recommend nor disapprove of thwate, they just had a reasonable description of it). In the general case though hosting multiple SSL sites behind a single public IP address [is a bit more tricky](https://serverfault.com/questions/109800/multiple-ssl-domains-on-the-same-ip-address-and-same-port).